# CSS Nesting Selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the below code, I am not understanding why we need to put `color:white` in a separate `.marked p`?
Why it's not working if I do `color:white` within `marked`? Can someone please explain?
Thanks in advance! :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p
{
color:blue;
text-align:center;
}
.marked
{
background-color:red;
}
.marked p
{
color:white;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>This paragraph has blue text, and is center aligned.</p>
<div class="marked">
<p>This paragraph has not blue text.</p>
</div>
<p>p elements inside a "marked" classed element keeps the alignment style, but has a different text color.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally a child element will [inherit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/inheritance) the color of its parent.

However, in this case, you have specifically added a color style to all `<p>` elements:

```
p { color:blue; text-align:center; }
```

That overrides any inherited styles that might have been set in `.marked` for this section of markup:

```
<div class="marked">
    <p>This paragraph has not blue text.</p>
</div>
```

The selector:

```
.marked p {}
```

has a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the element selector `p` by itself and overrides its value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do that because the `p` selector has less *specificity* than `.marked`. That's why you need to use `.marked p` in order to change the color.

You can learn about CSS specificity here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

Notice that text that isn't in a `p` tag will be blue. The fact that it's inside `marked` is irrelevant.